# Migration of mailboxes from Exchange Server 2010 to Office 365

Tags: azure

I want to migrate mailboxes from Exchange Server 2010 to Office 365. Here are the criteria:

1. Every mailbox is very large, so I want to split up only the past year of mail. This is the only mail that should be migrated; the rest should be archived. Is there any way to do that? How would I split up mail in Exchange Server?
2. I want to migrate the archived mail to separate storage, such as Azure storage, where I can access it. Can I migrate this archived mail into Azure storage? How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching sounds like "Exchange Online Archiving". Depending on your Office 365 subscription this is already part from your plan. If not you can order it.

1.)
Yes can be done, check Retention Tags and Retention Policies in combination with Exchange Archiving (e.g. Exchange Online Archiving as you asked to do that in the Azur cloud; more info's [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/archive-features-in-exchange-online-archiving.aspx) or [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd297955.aspx))

2.)
Yes, this is called "Exchange Online Archiving" see [here](https://products.office.com/en/exchange/microsoft-exchange-online-archiving-email) for features and how it works in general.

Comment: I have all the mailboxes in exchange server and have not migrated them yet. I would like to know these things before performing migration